# Can i render :partial a view without leading underscore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am facing a precarious condition here. I need to partially render a page that does not have a leading underscore.

```
<%= render(:partial => "contact" ,:controller=>"home") %>
```

this will look for

```
app/views/home/_contact.html.erb
```

but i want it to look for

```
app/views/home/contact.html.erb
```

is there a way of doing this.?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to do this though?

Comment: i am stuck in a precarious situation. The view i am trying to render is actually a view of a different controller with it's own layout. it is not used as a partial by that controller though. thats why.

Comment: I am also stuck in a similar situation. The view I'm trying to render as a partial is a template used by client-side javascript. On the client side it is a full view, but on the server-side it is just a partial. I don't want server-side conventions to mess up my client-side conventions. ^o^// the web gets complicated!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
<%= render :file => '/homes/contact' %>
```

Comment: it's not better without / before homes ?

Comment: thanks... should the :file path be complete and not local to contoller like..

    <%= render :file=>"contact" :controller=>"home" %>

Comment: @shingara, yes, but it's my habit to use absolute path, @ZX12R, no, you cant' you should use full path like "home/contact"

Answer (score 5):

You should not try to bypass the conventions if not really necessary. I guess contact.html.erb contains a form. Put this into `app/views/home/_contact.html.erb` and render it in `app/views/home/contact.html.erb`.

Or as fl00r answered:

```
<%= render :file => '/homes/contact' %>
```

Comment: The problem is that new use cases are starting to crop up, but the convention is getting in the way. Consider: I have js templates in my assets folders that belong to first-class controllers on the client side. I want to pre-render these templates in server-side views. So on the server-side, this is a partial. On the client side it is a view. Rails won't recognize a partial without the `_`, but sprockets won't compile a template with a leading `_`. Life is more complicated than conventions ^o^//

Answer (score 4):

As eteubert points out, one of the strengths of Rails is its opinionated nature. What you are trying to do here is bend that to your will. Don't. If you need to render something in another page as a partial, then you really should follow convention and extract a partial from the original page. If there's a form in that page for example, extract it out into a partial and have the original page render the partial as well.

You'll find the less you try to fight Rails, the easier things become.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following should also work:

```rb
render template: 'contact'
```

or

```rb
render template: 'homes/contact'
```